# How to Fix Bool Difference

Tags: mesh

So I'm trying to cut this particular shape and that works out well, but when I apply the bool modifier, it gets rid of the geometry and makes the cut completely empty. How can I fix it so it keeps the inner geometry?[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, have your tried the two options (Fast and Exact)? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes I have tried that to no avail, I'm uploading the file now :^)

Comment: heres the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/9d63b99dc3714a658150520e9688dd74

Answer (score 2):

You first need to apply the *Mirror* modifier, otherwise your mesh is opened and the *Boolean* won't act as expected.